# Angular 2 -- accessing value of radio button

Tags: angularjs, typescript

Within app.component.ts, I want to print out the actual value of the radio button clicked in the app.component.html.

app.component.html

```
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3 well" style="width: 20%">
        <h4>Narrow Your Results</h4>
        <div class="well">
            <h5>Rating</h5>
            <form [formGroup]="ratingForm">
                <input type="radio" formControlName="rating" value=100
                    (click)="filterByRating(ratingForm.value)"> All Grills
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.component.ts

```
@Component({
    selector: 'app-rootl',
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {

    ratingForm = new FormGroup({
        rating: new FormControl(),
    });


    filterByRating(rating: number) {
        console.log("rating = " + rating.valueOf());
    }
}
```

In `filterByRating()`, I expect `"rating=100"` to be printed out. I instead get `"rating = [object Object]"`

How do I access the value of the object?

Answer (score 2):

In your `(click)` event you are calling `filterByRating(ratingForm.value)`. The `ratingForm` variable is the entire form. You should pass just the radiobutton control. Something like this:

`<input type="radio" formControlName="rating" value=100 (click)="filterByRating(ratingForm.controls['rating'].value)">`